# req.body is empty in a mean stack app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, body-parser

I am attempting to make a polling app using node, express, and angular. On the front end they submit a form then send it to the back end with an http post request. When it finally reaches the proper route I log req.body and it is empty.

Everything I've read online says I probably messed up my body-parser middleware, so I have been messing with that for a while, but nothing has worked so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is my post on the front end:

```
    addVote(vote: Vote){
        const body = JSON.stringify(vote);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        console.log(body);
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            : '';
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/poll' + token, body, {headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            const vote = new Vote(result.obj.os, 1);
            console.log(result)
            return vote;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => console.error(error))
}
```

my middleware is this:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

and the back end route is here:

```
app.use('/poll', pollRoutes);
```

and here:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

P.S.: the console.log(body) in my front end, reads {"os":"MacOS","points":1}, which is what I would like to get to my back end. Thanks in advance!

P.S.S.: I took the {"os":"MacOS","points":1} that displayed to the console and entered it in postman and it worked just fine, so it has to be a problem with my angular code.

Comment: you are missing the route /poll?

Comment: You're posting to `http://localhost:8080/poll/` but gave us the backend route for `/`. What happens when you post to `router.post('/poll', fn)` where `fn` is your function callback of course.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, neither works

Comment: Is there an error in your browser console?

Comment: `return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/poll' + token, body, {headers})` looks suspicious.

Comment: I eventually get an http failure response but thats because I'm not sending anything back yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being my http usage. I tried using their new HttpClient instead of just http. When I did this, i did not switch the headers to the newer version, HttpHeaders and that is what broke it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues,

(i) You need to add the token under headers of the request

(ii) Inside your node.js express route configuration you should have a router defined with the url '/poll'

```
router.post('/poll', function(req, res) {
```

Comment: what do you mean in the headers? and also, there is a /poll route in my node configuration. that is what is sending me back the empty req.body

Comment: can you post the route in the question

Comment: what is pollRoutes?

Comment: const pollRoutes = require('./routes/poll'); it is just where it is sending anything with /poll

Comment: your're doing something totally wrong. check this sample app https://github.com/sajeetharan/angular4-crud-node-mongoose-bootstrap4

Comment: Haha, I am well aware that I am, just trying to figure out what. will do

Comment: So my pollRoutes is essentially the same thing as api is in your example

Comment: so still not sorted?

Comment: sadly, not yet.